# Python ImportError: No module named cv

Tags: python

Im just new to Python and trying to run a scripts online [code here](https://github.com/abidrahmank/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/Other_Examples/multi_color_two_object.py)

However one error occurred:

```
File "C:\Python27\track.py", line 1,in <module>
import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5):

Install OpenCV

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

It needs this package to function

Comment: Is there new link? The link doesn't have any information anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at here http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20%3A%20Debian, 'Making Python work';

third option worked for me but there is a bug there, the correct line to add bashrc is

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

this can vary according to your python installation though.

Comment: The weblink looks like invalid, please update thanks.