# No module named cv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to run this script:

https://github.com/openalpr/train-detector/blob/master/crop_plates.py

I've never dealt with python before. First of all I had some syntax errors in the print lines. They were lacking parentheses...but I'm not sure if I get this error because of the Python version I installed or this was indeed a syntax error. After fixing the syntax error I'm receiving the following error:

```
C:\>py crop_plates.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crop_plates.py", line 7, in <module>
import cv2, cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

I did the following:

Installed Python 2.7.5 32 bits.

Installed numpy 1.9.1 32 bits (also tried different versions)

Installed matplotlib 1.3.0.

Installed OpenCv

Copied cv2.pyd from

```
C:\Users\Me\Downloads\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86
```

to

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

But I can't find anywhere the cv.pyd file that I'm missing.

I found references to this guide for installing Opencv but it's not working
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/

Thank you very much,

Edit: I'm running Python in Windows 7.

Comment: In python 3, print statements expect parenthesis but not so in python 2. Thus, the first error is due to python version.

Comment: Allright, I first tried with python 3 now with python 2 I don't get syntax error however the other error still shows

Comment: why the downvote, whoever made it? I don't get it

Answer (score 7):

For `ImportError: No module named cv`, try installing `opencv-python` module using below command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: @Vallo - Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497033/python-importerror-no-module-named-cv?

Comment: Sounds like you've to build OpenCV from source. Please see if this is helpful https://avinton.com/en/academy/install-python2-7-opencv/

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm running windows but I've found another guide for Windows. Thank you

Comment: I had the error in uploading images in Wagtail 2.8. You save my time a lot! I could handle it by installing this package. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`cv2.cv` **doesn't exists in OpenCV 3.0**. Use simply `cv2`

Also, the attribute is no more **CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT** but **HOUGH_GRADIENT**

So what you looking for is probably:

```
cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT
```

Answer (score 1):

OK , I searched for a while and find the following :

- First: you may write: `import cv2.cv as cv` to solve your proplem
- `cv` and `cv2` are both interface for python , and now , the newest "`cv2`" is the most used one , but clearly some libraries still use `cv` and others (like yours) use mix of the two,[What is different between all these OpenCV Python interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces)

Comment: Almost...     moment = cv2.Moments(points) 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Moments'

Comment: I'm gonna look if there's an equivalent of Moments for cv2

Comment: But I guess the original error is solved and this is another issue

Comment: I get this error if i add the .cv extension   `File "crop_plates1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cv2.cv as cv
ImportError: No module named cv`

Comment: ok , this is opencv3 , the mere setting to `cv2` should work , you type the function wrong....

Comment: Originally Moments was with capital M and it shows `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Moments'`

Comment: try parsing points array to a numpy array before using it. e.g. np.int32(points)

Comment: this is not going to work. because cv means an older distribution of python. this cv2.cv wont help

Comment: @Vallo, have you find the solution for Moments?

Comment: When I use **moment = cv2.moments(points)**, it shows another error: **TypeError: array is not a numpy array, neither a scalar**. Apparently this two moments are different function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code is using a old version of OpenCV.  Unfortunately there is no mention of the exact version they used in their repo.

As the code is at least 2 years old, I would install opencv version 2.4.

`pip install opencv-python==2.4`