# TypeError: array is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to run this script but I get this error

"TypeError: array is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"
on line 60

```
 moment = cv.moments(points)
```

I didn't make the script, it is from here

https://github.com/openalpr/train-detector/blob/master/crop_plates.py

and I modified it a bit in order to work

- changed "import cv" to "import cv2 as cv" since I couldn't make it work (ref: [No module named cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675823/no-module-named-cv))
- changed line 60 from "moment = cv.Moments(points)" to "moment = cv.moments(points)" (the capital M)

the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import json
import math
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import copy
import yaml
from argparse import ArgumentParser


parser = ArgumentParser(description='OpenALPR License Plate Cropper')

parser.add_argument( "--input_dir", dest="input_dir", action="store", type=str, required=True, 
                  help="Directory containing plate images and yaml metadata" )

parser.add_argument( "--out_dir", dest="out_dir", action="store", type=str, required=True, 
                  help="Directory to output cropped plates" )

parser.add_argument( "--zoom_out_percent", dest="zoom_out_percent", action="store", type=float, default=1.25, 
                  help="Percent multiplier to zoom out before cropping" )

parser.add_argument( "--plate_width", dest="plate_width", action="store", type=float, required=True, 
                  help="Desired aspect ratio width" )
parser.add_argument( "--plate_height", dest="plate_height", action="store", type=float, required=True, 
                  help="Desired aspect ratio height" )

options = parser.parse_args()


if not os.path.isdir(options.input_dir):
    print "input_dir (%s) doesn't exist"
    sys.exit(1)


if not os.path.isdir(options.out_dir):
    os.makedirs(options.out_dir)



def get_box(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4):
    height1 = int(round(math.sqrt((x1-x4)*(x1-x4) + (y1-y4)*(y1-y4))))
    height2 = int(round(math.sqrt((x3-x2)*(x3-x2) + (y3-y2)*(y3-y2))))

    height = height1
    if height2 > height:
        height = height2

    # add 25% to the height
    height *= options.zoom_out_percent
    #height += (height * .05)

    #print "Height: %d - %d" % (height1, height2)


    points = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4)]
    moment = cv.moments(points)
    centerx = int(round(moment.m10/moment.m00))
    centery = int(round(moment.m01/moment.m00))


    training_aspect = options.plate_width / options.plate_height
    width = int(round(training_aspect * height))

    # top_left = ( int(centerx - (width / 2)), int(centery - (height / 2)))
    # bottom_right = ( int(centerx + (width / 2)), int(centery + (height / 2)))

    top_left_x = int(round(centerx - (width / 2)))
    top_left_y = int(round(centery - (height / 2)))

    return (top_left_x, top_left_y, width, int(round(height)))

def crop_rect(big_image, x,y,width,height):
    # Crops the rectangle from the big image and returns a cropped image
    # Special care is taken to avoid cropping beyond the edge of the image.
    # It fills this area in with random pixels

    (big_height, big_width, channels) = big_image.shape
    if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and (y+height) < big_height and (x+width) < big_width:
        crop_img = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
    else:
        #print "Performing partial crop"
        #print "x: %d  y: %d  width: %d  height: %d" % (x,y,width,height)
        #print "big_width: %d  big_height: %d" % (big_width, big_height)
        crop_img = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        cv2.randu(crop_img, (0,0,0), (255,255,255))

        offset_x = 0
        offset_y = 0
        if x < 0:
            offset_x = -1 * x
            x = 0
            width -= offset_x
        if y < 0:
            offset_y = -1 * y
            y = 0
            height -= offset_y
        if (x+width) >= big_width:
            offset_x = 0
            width = big_width - x
        if (y+height) >= big_height:
            offset_y = 0
            height = big_height - y

        #print "offset_x: %d  offset_y: %d, width: %d, height: %d" % (offset_x, offset_y, width, height)

        original_crop =  img[y:y+height-1, x:x+width-1]
        (small_image_height, small_image_width, channels) = original_crop.shape
        #print "Small shape: %dx%d" % (small_image_width, small_image_height)
        # Draw the small image onto the large image
        crop_img[offset_y:offset_y+small_image_height, offset_x:offset_x+small_image_width] = original_crop


    #cv2.imshow("Test", crop_img)
    return crop_img

count = 1
yaml_files = []
for in_file in os.listdir(options.input_dir):
    if in_file.endswith('.yaml') or in_file.endswith('.yml'):
        yaml_files.append(in_file)


yaml_files.sort()

for yaml_file in yaml_files:


    print "Processing: " + yaml_file + " (" + str(count) + "/" + str(len(yaml_files)) + ")"
    count += 1


    yaml_path = os.path.join(options.input_dir, yaml_file)
    yaml_without_ext = os.path.splitext(yaml_path)[0]
    with open(yaml_path, 'r') as yf:
        yaml_obj = yaml.load(yf)

    image = yaml_obj['image_file']

    # Skip missing images
    full_image_path = os.path.join(options.input_dir, image)
    if not os.path.isfile(full_image_path):
        print "Could not find image file %s, skipping" % (full_image_path)
        continue


    plate_corners = yaml_obj['plate_corners_gt']
    cc = plate_corners.strip().split()
    for i in range(0, len(cc)):
        cc[i] = int(cc[i])

    box = get_box(cc[0], cc[1], cc[2], cc[3], cc[4], cc[5], cc[6], cc[7])


    img = cv2.imread(full_image_path)
    crop = crop_rect(img, box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3])

    # cv2.imshow("test", crop)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    out_crop_path = os.path.join(options.out_dir, yaml_without_ext + ".jpg")
    cv2.imwrite(out_crop_path, crop )

print "%d Cropped images are located in %s" % (count-1, options.out_dir)
```

I don't have any knowledge of Python. I could either find a way to solve this error or find out how to install module cv.

OS is Windows 7, Python is 2.7
Thanks,

Comment: You didn't follow the suggestion in your linked answer exactly. You have `import cv2 as cv` but the answer says `import cv2.cv as cv`

Comment: Check my comment below that answer, i get this error: http://imgur.com/WIZh0EK

Comment: This is not a debugging service. What have *you done* to try to debug this? The error message is clear - the function expects an array, but does't recognize `points` as an array. Have you tried putting a debugging `print(points, type(points))` before the function call? You'll note, it is a `list`, not a `numpy.ndarray`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm posting here because I believe the script works and I'm having trouble running it, but maybe I should just contact the one who wrote it and ask him whats going on

Comment: @Vallo did you try with the `opencv-python` method?

Comment: Yes, and nothing changed https://i.imgur.com/D6mwE4H.png

Comment: hey @Vallo did you fix that? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No i didin't, I contacted the developer and ended up using the comercial license because it fitted better for my project.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try printing the contents of "Points" before calculating the moments.
2. If there is nothing wrong with the "Points", try `cv.Moments(np.int32(points))`

Comment: I was looking for hours why my array was wrong and this was it, thanks!