# How to install `cv` for Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I pip-installed *opencv-python* and now I can do `import cv2`. But `import cv` fails:

```
ImportError: No module named 'cv'
```

I need `cv` because API of some classes, for example [VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#cv2.VideoCapture), require constants that are defined there.

Comment: You have a code which is for old opencv. Install opencv version 2.4

Comment: opencv2 and opencv are 2 different libraries and they don't require each other to my knowledge, could you post an example of where you require 'cv'

Comment: `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url); video_fps = capture.get(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)`
leads to: `AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_FPS'`
From what I've found out, these contants are defined in `cv`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turned out I was misled by [an old version of documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=videocapture#cv2.VideoCapture.get) (for some reason search engine placed link to this version on top) that uses constants like `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS`. Also I've seen some code previously that used `cv` and not `cv2` to get to these constants (but it was a while ago and I guess it was for Python 2 and some old version of *opencv*).

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52781285/1203941) I realized that names of the constants changed between versions of *opencv*. [A new version of docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) seems to confirm that -- prefix `CV_` is no longer there. I checked that the constants that I need are accessible from `cv2`, for example

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("film.webm")
video_fps = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print("fps", video_fps)
```

works fine!